# VB.NET: GetFiles Method - "Access to the path 'G:\System Volume Information' is denied."

Tags: vb.net, path, unauthorized, getfiles

Here is my code,

```
Dim allFiles As FileInfo() = 
                        tempDir.GetFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

I've googled and found that I need to change the permissions of my app from 
`Project properties > View UAC Settings > and change level to level="requireAdministrator"`

But its also not working. I found something about `FileIOPermission` class, but dont know how to implement it.

==> Detailed code.

```
Dim tempDir As New DirectoryInfo(path)
        Dim FileDetails(4) As String
        Dim iTem As ListViewItem
        If (tempDir.Attributes <> FileAttributes.System) Then
            Dim allFiles As FileInfo() = tempDir.GetFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Dim oneFIle As FileInfo
            For Each oneFIle In allFiles
                FileDetails(0) = oneFIle.Name()
                FileDetails(1) = oneFIle.FullName()
                FileDetails(2) = oneFIle.Length() / (1024 * 1024)
                FileDetails(2) = FileDetails(2).Remove(5)
                iTem = New ListViewItem(FileDetails)
                ListView1.Items.Add(iTem)
            Next
        End If
```

Path is a string that contains the path required, in this case `G:\`

Comment: How is tempDir initialized in this case?

Comment: I guess the error message says it all: access denied. Please provide more details about how the contents of the path is secured and why/how you want to access it.

Comment: Actually I want to scan the whole drive for PDF files. Editing the post with detailed code..

Comment: Is G: a NT share on a domain server?...maybe you need to use the UNC formatted name for this to work? Or the fact that G: drive is locked down...therefore using require administrator privileges will not work as that is a local thing not remote...

Comment: Hey hey, G:\ is just a local disk of mine.

Comment: @Bibhas: You should have mentioned that in your question... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved the case, I just iterated each folder, checked their attributes and then added to the list.. I think it's working.. Plz check it a bit..

```
Dim tempDir As New DirectoryInfo(path)
    Dim FileDetails(4) As String
    Dim iTem As ListViewItem
    Try
        Dim allFiles As FileInfo() = Nothing 
        For Each Directory In tempDir.GetDirectories()
            Try
                If (Directory.Attributes <> FileAttributes.System) Then
                    allFiles = Directory.GetFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                End If
                Dim oneFIle As FileInfo

                For Each oneFIle In allFiles
                    FileDetails(0) = oneFIle.Name()
                    FileDetails(1) = oneFIle.FullName()
                    FileDetails(2) = oneFIle.Length() / (1024 * 1024)
                    FileDetails(2) = FileDetails(2).Remove(5)
                    iTem = New ListViewItem(FileDetails)
                    ListView1.Items.Add(iTem)                        
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        Next
    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException

    End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't find PDF files in this folder:

> The `System Volume Information` folder is a hidden system folder that the System Restore tool uses to store its information and restore points. ([MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;309531&x=16&y=13))

So just ignore it.

Granted, `GetFiles()` does not allow you to ignore files/folders, so you'd have to PInvoke into [FindFirstFile](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.FindFirstFile) et al. to do searches effectively.

Comment: Only the SYSTEM account has access to this folder.

Comment: So, I cannot ignore that folder.. Ok, Can you provide a modified `simple` code to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

System Volume Information Folder is a O/S protected folder.  Even though you may have administrative access, you still will not be able to access it.  You can try it from Explorer itself.  (Need to enable option to show protected Operating System files.)